# how to set the delay of ajax loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

my code is like following:
the problem is when I scroll to the end of the page,it will load data many times.if I have 10 elements in the page,and I load data from "/api/get_more_application/10",but before the loading done,jquery will send ajax to the "/api/get_more_application/10" second time before the dom added to the page,so maybe the solution should like,you can't send second request to url before the last request done,how to do that? thx

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var window_height = $(window).height(); 
    var i = 1; 
    $(window).scroll(function () { 
        var page_height = $(document.body).height(); 
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        var delta = page_height-window_height-scroll_top;   
        if(delta<100){ 
            random_number = Math.random();
            dom_num = $(".item").size();
            $.get("/api/get_more_application/"+dom_num+"?"+random_number,function(data,status){
                var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                data_list_length = json_data.data_list.length;

                if (data_list_length === 0){
                    $(".nodata").show();
                }

                $.each(json_data.data_list,function(){
                    var dict_data = {
                        "admin": admin,
                        "id": this.id,
                        "limit_save_number": this.limit_save_number,
                        "employeeid": this.employeeid,
                        "appname": this.appname,
                        "filetype": this.filetype,
                        "applicant_im": this.applicant_im,
                        "onlinestor_quota": this.onlinestor_quota,
                        "employee": this.employee,
                        "apply_content": this.apply_content
                    };

                    $.get("approveditem.html",function(html_data,status){
                        replaced_str = html_data.replace(/<<(\w+?)>>/g,function($0,$1){ 
                            var value = dict_data[$1];
                            return value;
                        });
                        $("#items_container").append(replaced_str);
                    })
                });
            });
            auto_data_set();    
        };  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery's sleep function:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

To call the function:

> sleep(1000); // 1 second

Comment: if there is a better way?if just set a timeout,if the network is very bad,it will load the data long time and occur some error

Comment: sleep will have some stall on the page,it make the web badly

Comment: Yes, I see you problem. This might be your solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956116/is-it-possible-to-run-code-after-all-ajax-call-completed-under-the-for-loop-stat

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/